# Limit WD mobile (2.5”) to 1.5 gig per second

Tags: hard-drive, jumper

Dealing with some legacy hardware that needs 1.5 gig per second limit to read drives. I got this going with a WD black 3.5”, but I cannot find jumper settings for WD 2.5 mobile to do this. Is it even possible?

Comment: HDDs have no settings to limit data transfer speeds. The limiting factor is the SATA (or other) controller they're connected to. A SATA III drive is retro-compatible with SATA II and SATA I.

Comment: 3.5" drives have a jumper setting that limits speeds to 1.5:

See OPT1: https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=981 I wonder if there is something similar for mobile drives?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible on WD mobile drives (2.5"). Only WD 3.5" drives have the jumper options to limit the speed based on hardware pin configurations.